# Builtin function to apply single expression with multiple variables

Tags: python

Is there an existing Python builtin function which assigns two or more variables and returns multiple values upon assigning a single expression? For example:

hypothetically:

```
attrs, patterns, weight = [] * 3
```

is the same as:

```
attrs, patterns, weight = [], [], []
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. What does "assigns two or more variables and returns multiple values upon assigning a single expression" mean?

Comment: He meant assigning the same value to multiple variable without writing the value multiple times

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The example above would return `[], [], []` upon assigning 3 lists with the expression `[] * 3` (hypothetically).

Comment: @mamun do they? So `attrs`, `patterns` and `weight` should have the same value?

Comment: @PyHunterMan three *different* lists? No there is no built-in function. You can trivially write one yourself, though. Here, `[[] for _ in range(3)]` would work on the right-hand side

Comment: `attrs`, `patterns`, `weight` should contain different values that will append after.

Comment: I don't understand how `attrs, patterns, weight = [], [], []` doesn't just do what you need. There is no general function for create `N` number of some arbitrary object.

Answer (score 2):

The best existing syntax for that is

```
attrs, patterns, weight = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

which isn't really an improvement over `[], [], []`. It has an advantage for complex expressions, though.

If you wanted a function, you'd run into the problem that Python functions take objects, not expressions. A function can't evaluate its argument expressions repeatedly. If you wanted to write a function, you'd have to wrap the expression in a `lambda` or something:

```
def n_times(constructor, n):
    return [constructor() for i in range(n)]

attrs, patterns, weight = n_times(lambda: [], 3)
# or
attrs, patterns, weight = n_times(list, 3)
```

There are a few tempting but wrong options:

```
# Mistake
attrs = patterns = weight = []
# Also a mistake
attrs, patterns, weight = [[]]*3
```

which assign the *same* list to each variable instead of making separate lists, because Python assignment doesn't make copies, and list multiplication doesn't copy the elements, only references to the elements.

Comment: I'm looking forward Python creators to integrate this in the future version of Python.

Comment: @PyHunterMan: Don't hold your breath.

Comment: Would be happy if I can see like this in the future: `attrs, patterns, weight = [*3]`

Comment: @PyHunterMan that's almost certainly not going to happen. It adds almost zero functionality over `[],[],[]` and would add unnecessary complexity to the parser for dubious benefit.

Comment: The variable i is redundant in your answers. Why not jyst use _ underscore

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the behaviour you're trying to have, you can create a custom object that behaves like this expression: `var1, var2, var3 = __OBJECT__ * 3`

Here is an example:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

class Custom:   
     def __init__(self, initial=[]):
         if not isinstance(initial, Iterable):
             raise ValueError()
         self.initial = initial
         self.args = initial

     def __mul__(self, args):
         self.args = [self.initial[:] for _ in range(args)]
         return self.args

     def __iter__(self):
         for _ in range(len(self.args)):
             yield self.initial

     def __repr__(self):
         return '{}'.format(list(self))
```

Demo:

```
$> a, b, c = Custom() * 3
$> print(a, b, c) # [] [] []
$> id(a) == id(b) == id(c) # False

$> a, b, c = Custom(()) * 3
$> print(a, b, c) # () () ()
$> id(a) == id(b) == id(c) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b = c = []
```

All variables are independently set to the same value. (Caution: the same mutable object, but that is true of any multiple assignment in Python.)

See the documentation of the [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt) - multiple `target_list "="` sections are allowed.

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list [...] and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

This was a surprise to me when I first tried it in an immediate session! But it works just as you'd expect.